# How to force culture/region on RegionInfo.DisplayName

Tags: c#, regioninfo

I'm displaying a country as part of some other information.
The country is read out of a database as a country code.

This is done like so:

```
Location location = new Location()
{                                
    Company = reader.GetString("Company"),
    Address1 = reader.GetString("Address"),
    Address2 = reader.GetString("Address2", string.Empty),
    ZipCity = reader.GetString("ZipCity"),
    Country = new RegionInfo(reader.GetString("Country", string.Empty)).DisplayName,
    CountryCode = new RegionInfo(reader.GetString("Country", string.Empty)).TwoLetterISORegionName,
    Att = reader.GetString("Att", string.Empty),
    Phone = reader.GetString("Phone", string.Empty)
};
```

My problem is that I would really like to force the display name to be in danish.
Mind you, the country will now always be denmark, so using native name is not an option.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `Country =  new RegionInfo(...).NativeName;` ?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/da-DK/download/details.aspx?id=30667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after checking into the possibility of installing a language pack for the .NET Framework, which for some reason wasn't possible for us, we found the following solution.

Add this line to your web.config under the system.web node.

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da"/>
```

If you have a OS language pack installed on the machine running your software, it will now be forced to that language.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas, the web.config trick helped me.  But I don't understand why I must use that in the web.config, and why these lines does not work:

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("fr")
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("fr")

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.displayname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The DisplayName property displays the country/region name in the
>   language of the **localized version of .NET Framework**. For example, the
>   DisplayName property displays the country/region in English on the
>   English version of the .NET Framework, and in Spanish on the Spanish
>   version of the .NET Framework.

So, if you install the Danish version of .NET, it should work as you want.

However, it may be better to not depend on that and just create your own table of Danish country names.

Comment: I was hoping not having to resolve to that, since that would mean manually maintaning country names, country codes and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by writing that line before instanciating RegionInfo :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
```