# C# get RegionInfo, TwoLetterISORegionName, by Swedish country name

Tags: c#, globalization

I need to get the two letter ISO region name, `ISO 3166` - `ISO 3166-1 alpha 2`, for countries. My problem is that I only have the country names in Swedish, for example `Sverige` for `Sweden` and `Tyskland` for `Germany`. Is it possible to get RegionInfo from only this information? I know it is possible for English country names.

Works:

```
var countryName = "Sweden";
//var countryName = "Denmark";
var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));
var englishRegion = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName.Contains(countryName));
var twoLetterISORegionName = englishRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262292/3850405

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try comparing with [`NativeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.nativename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string nativeName = "Sverige"; // Sweden

var region = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.LCID))
    .FirstOrDefault(rg => rg.NativeName == nativeName);

Console.Write($"{region.TwoLetterISORegionName}");
```

**Edit:** It seems that we actually want to find out `RegionInfo` instance by its **Swedish** name

```
  Sverige  -> Sweden
  Tyskland -> Germany
  ...
```

In this case we should use [`DisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `NativeName`:

```
string swedishName = "Sverige"; // Sweden

var region = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.LCID))
    .FirstOrDefault(rg => rg.DisplayName == swedishName);
```

and we should be sure that we use **localized** .Net

> The DisplayName property displays the country/region name **in the
>   language of the localized version** of .NET Framework. For example,
>   the DisplayName property displays the country/region in English on the
>   English version of the .NET Framework, and in Spanish on the Spanish
>   version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Works fine with `Sverige` and `Danmark` but fails with for example `Tyskland` for `Germany`.

Comment: It should be `Deutschland` (Native name) in case of `Germany` (English name), `Danmark` in case of `Denmark`, `Ελλάδα` in case of `Greece` etc.

Comment: Yes but the saved value I have is `Tyskland` for `Germany`. :)

Comment: Another possibility is to put `DisplayName` instead of `NativeName` but it requires *localized* (Swedish) .Net version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408154/how-to-force-culture-